# open text file and make each line a new string element in array

Tags: php, string, file

In php, how can I open and read in a text file and make each line of type string and an element in an array?

My plan is then to use a `foreach` to travel through the array and use `in_array()` to look for words in the contents of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

```
$lines = file('path/to/file');

foreach($lines as $line)
{

  //enjoy

}
```